# How to display EnumSet in JSP file in custom order?

Tags: java, jsp, enumset

I have an `java.util.EnumSet` containing a lot of elements that is being displayed as a drop down list (`JSP`). Now, by default they're sorted by `ID`:

```
1 Toyota
2 Honda
3 Audi
4 BMW
```

What I want to achieve is the list in alphabetic order:

```
3 Audi
4 BMW
2 Honda
1 Toyota
```

Can I change the order of displaying the enums on the drop down list without changing their IDs?

Comment: Yes. Copy the elements to a list, and sort the list the way you want to. Iterate through the list to generate the options of the dropdown. Note that enums don't have an ID. They have a name, and an ordinal. Their natural order is the order of their ordinal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an ordered `Collection` from the `EnumSet` and then use that in JSP. However then you won't be getting benefits of `EnumSet`, in that case there's no need to use it in the first place.

Check following sample for creating desired ordered `List`

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.EnumSet;
import java.util.List;

public class TestEnumSet {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Started\n");

        EnumSet<Cars> set = EnumSet.of(Cars.Toyata, Cars.Audi, Cars.Honda, Cars.BMW);

        List<Cars> list = Arrays.asList(set.toArray(new Cars[]{}));
        list.sort((a, b) -> a.toString().compareTo(b.toString()));

        list.stream().forEach(a -> System.out.println(a.id + " : " + a.toString()));

        System.out.println("\nFnished");
    }

    public static enum Cars {
        Toyata(1), Audi(2), Honda(3), BMW(4);

        int id;
        Cars(int id ) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Started

2 : Audi
4 : BMW
3 : Honda
1 : Toyata

Fnished
```

Comment: Since you're using streams, you could create a sorted list in one step using `set.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Object::toString)).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: There's a weird compilation error coming using `set.stream()...`, `The method t‌​oList() is undefined for the type Collectors`